# div with flex display items hover not growing above other items

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add div with flex display with `flex-wrap: wrap` as container `<div>` and it contains item `<div>` the grow in size on hover. My problem is on hover, item go new line. I want to item stay in same position and float above other items.

```css
.item {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: xx-large;
}

.item:hover {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap;">
  <div class="item">
    item 1
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item 2
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item 3
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item 4
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want the item to grow in width and overlap the next one ? what you mean by `float above other items`

Comment: i want the item grow and be above the next one because if hove on last one it keep  Jumps to new line and return to it position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One hacky way to do it is to use pseudo-element of the hovered element to cover the one next to it, However when it comes to the elements placed on the right it's another story.

using position relative we can push them from the right and use pseudo-element again to mimic the extension of the width, because if we do increase the width
the element will wrap thanks to your `flex-wrap:wrap;`

Which means this is just visual if there's long content it won't work that good, and you'll have to keep overflow visible.

```css
.item {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  /* overflow: hidden; */      /* Removed  */ 
  font-size: xx-large;
  position: relative;
}

.item:hover {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.item:before {
  height: 100%;
  background: lightgreen;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.item:hover:before {
  content: '';
}

/* select only the elements on right side */
.item:nth-child(2n):hover {
  right: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap;">
  <div class="item">item 1</div>
  <div class="item">item 2</div>
  <div class="item">item 3</div>
  <div class="item">item 4</div>
</div>
```

i suggest you rethink your layout if you want to achieve your desired end result.

Answer (score 1):

If you have flex wrap on, anything over the containers width (default 100%) will be put on a new line, where you currently have 50% and trying to add 70% it will not keep it on the same line

To achieve the result you want you could put the lines in their own containers shown below

```
<div class="item-container">
      <div class="item">
        item 1
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        item 2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <div class="item">
        item 3
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        item 4
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
.item-container {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  flex: 50%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: xx-large;
}

.item:hover {
  flex: 70%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```